# Optionnal parameter for a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, function, overloading

I want to write an overload of a function in javascript. I tried optional parameter but it don't work.
What I tried:

```
let myFunction = (foo, bar) => {
 foo = (foo || 'FOO');
 console.log(foo + " " + bar);
}
```

Here I expect: **foo bar**

```
myFunction("foo","bar");
```

Here I expect: **FOO bar**

```
myFunction("bar");
```

Anyone knows how to pass optional parameters to a function ?

Comment: You've passed that string as the *first* argument. If you want to pass it as the second argument, and pass nothing to `foo`, then use `myFunction(undefined, "bar")`. In general, the optional parameters should always come last.

Comment: you could have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48327804/1447675), if that is, what you want.

Comment: Does null work as well?

Comment: The way you've currently written your function, even `false` would work. Of course, if `foo` were the second parameter, you wouldn't have to pass anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass only the second argument in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569300/pass-only-the-second-argument-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to call a function with every parameters. Even with `undefined` values.

To obtain **FOO bar**

```
 myFunction( undefined, "bar")
```

[Working js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dz2hocf6/)

p.s: it's working with `null` as well

Comment: "It's important to call a function with every parameters" isn't always true. It's rare for people to pass 2 arguments to `Array.prototype.map()`, for example.